# Updating new dictionary keys + increment old dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am constantly generating playlists with this structure:

```
playlist =  {u'user1': {u'Roads': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0, u'Go It Alone': 1.0}}
```

and I upload it to a directory. Then I check if file has already been uploaded before.

```
if os.path.exists('db/playlist.json'):
            with open('playlist.json', 'r+') as f:
                plist = json.load(f)
                # increment track count
                updateTrackCounts(db_1,value=1)
                #update json here
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                json.dump(plist, f)
                print (plist)
```

I am using this working function `updateTrackCounts()` suggested by @Moses Koledoye, that increments track `counts` by one.

```
def updateTrackCounts(d, value=0):
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i], dict):
            updateTrackCounts(d[i], value)
        elif isinstance(d[i], float):
            d[i] += value

updateTrackCounts(playlist, value=1)
```

but sometimes the new `playlist` generated will have new `keys`, that were not present in the `dictionary` generated before.

How do I tweak the code above so it makes `increment function` apply to pre existing `keys` on the pre existing `file`, and update `plist` to always contemplate new `keys` with `value` = `1.0`?

Desired result with one new key in `inner` `dictionary`:

```
playlist =  {u'user1': {u'Bittersweet Symphony':1.0, u'Roads': 2.0, u'Pyramid Song': 2.0, u'Go It Alone': 2.0}}
```

Comment: @Moses Koledoye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d.get(i,0)
```

returns the value for key `i` if such key exists, else `0`. So instead of

```
d[i] += value
```

you could write

```
d[i] = d.get(i,0) + value
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should start by better labeling your variables.

You could alway just use a try except

```
try:
    d[i] += value
except KeyError:
    d[i] = 1.0
```

This is better than an if statement because for the most part you won't be adding new keys and this will be faster when a key does not need to be added.

Comment: did you notice the new `key` with `value:1.0` (new item) in the desired output?

Comment: Ok I changed` d[i] = value` to `d[i] = 1.0` in the answer. So, that should initialize the new key to 1.0

Comment: __never__ use a bare except clause, always use the expected exception type. You wouldn't want an existing key to be reset to `1.0` if `value` happened to be a string, `None` or just any type you can't add to a float or int, do you ?

Comment: That was super hard to fix. Thanks for the catch though